# How to use GZIP compression for my Weebly website

Tags: compression, gzip, weebly

I have a website created with weebly but it is slow as weebly does not uses GZIP compression. How can I use it with Weebly?

Comment: Are you really sure it is slow because it doesn't use compression?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming questions. This is more server configuration.

Comment: No. But it has to be configured somewhere within the website. And that's what I want to know.